# MVC4, jQuery Mobile and Javascript auto submit only working once until refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dropdown list that auto submits a form and performs a search that I use throughout a project via a partial view, but it only works the first time I use it, unless I refresh the page. It’s an MVC 4 with jQuery Mobile project.

Here is the code I have in my partial view,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#CoastLineID").change(function () {
            var actionUrl = $('#TheForm').attr('action') + '/' + $('#CoastLineID').val();
             $('#TheForm').attr('action', actionUrl);
             $('#TheForm').submit();
         });
    });
</script>
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchCoast", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm" }))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("CoastLineID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ArticleId, "Select a Coastline")
    }
</p>
```

I guess I need to be able to refresh the page or the list each time a page/view that uses the partial view is loaded somehow. Is this a jQuery issue???

Any ideas, I can put the URL up for the site if I’m allowed to?

**Update/Edit**

Thanks guys,

I’ve come across a few issues mixing jQuery Mobile and MVC and mostly due to the way they both handle URL strings differently, all coming from 15 years of web development. All the jQuery Mobile docs deal with classic URL strings e.g.. about/us.html which is not the MVC way!

This is my controller code to populate the dropdown,

```
var coastlines = db.CoastLines.Select(c => new { c.CoastLineID, c.CoastLineName });
ViewBag.CoastLineId = new SelectList(coastlines.AsEnumerable(), "CoastLineID", "CoastLineName", 0);
```

And this is the web site,

http://www.peninsulaguide.com.au/

Click “Beach Search” and then “Select a Coastline” or “Select a Town” will work but nothing after that without a refresh.

There are two dropdowns but it doesn’t make a difference if I remove one.

Cheers,

Mike

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the conroller that the form calls, is it getting hit? As far as I know, there's nothing preventing you from resubmitting a form unless you take action to block it. I've built jQuery forms before that could be resubmitted, and I had to clear the values on submit to prevent it.

Comment: The URL would be helpful and is allowed, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure without seeing the entire page, but a likely cause of your problem is that the dropdownlist on the part of the page which is reloaded when the form is posted.

If that is so, your problem is that you are hooking up an event handler to one dropdownlist, and then expects that event handler to handle change events from all later dropdownlists that are given the same id.

Read up on the `.live()` method in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/), and then change your code to this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#CoastLineID").live('change', function () {
        var actionUrl = $('#TheForm').attr('action') + '/' + $('#CoastLineID').val();
         $('#TheForm').attr('action', actionUrl);
         $('#TheForm').submit();
     });
});
```

**Note:** If you're using jQuery 1.7 or later, `.live()` is deprecated and should be replaced by `.on()`. To accomplish this, replace

```
$("#CoastLineID").live('change', function () { ... });
```

with

```
$(document).on('change', '#CoastLineID', function () { ... });
```

Details can be found in the [documentation for `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Thanks to stian.net for pointing this out.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers

Comment: @stian.net: Thanks for the pointer! Hadn't noticed that, as I haven't used jQuery 1.7+ extensively yet. Edited the post to include this information.

Comment: You guys are so  clever, it has fixed it but I get the "Error loading page" popup each time but it works, what would that be? its very hard to test jQuery Mobile as it doesn't give me error messages!

Comment: it also only works once after a refresh and not at all if I go too the gallery!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing seems completely valid. Forms can be resubmitted as many times as you like, unless you take steps to prevent it, and partial views shouldn't have any impact on this.

Partial views are simply an ASP.NET MVC contrivance to allow you to share snippets of HTML among pages. Once the page is rendered to the browser, you're just dealing with HTML and jQuery.

The most likely culprit is a bug in your jQuery. It's hard to work out without seeing the HTML that's getting rendered, but I'm guessing that one of two things is happening:

1. You might be resubmitting the same search over and over due to how you're selecting the value to submit.
2. The event isn't firing correctly each time the dropdown menu selection is changed.

As far as trouble shooting, try:

- Setting a breakpoint in your controller to see if it's getting called at all and what search terms are coming back in the request.
- Adding a `console.log('something')` statement inside your `change` callback function to make sure that it is in face getting called every time the selection is changed.

If you'll post a link to your site, I'll be glad to take a look at the jQuery side.